# Entity Framework Automatic migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have a 3-tier architecture project (Web, Service, DataAccess), I just want to migrate the database to latest version whenever POCO changes happen. We can do this by calling the automatic migration code from `Application_Start` event. In this scenario, I don't have the reference of the `DataAccess` project in my web. So how can I call the automatic migration code from `Application_Start` event?

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<BlogContext, Configuration>());
```

I can't access the `BlogContext` from `Application_Start`.

Please help me

Thanks in advance
[In Production environment, we can't run update-database command thru VS, so is there any other way to update the database automatically)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.   If your Web Project communicates with the database at all, it should have a reference to your `DataAcess` project.  If it doesn't, and you have some other "business layer" in between, then define a function in the business layer that does the migration, and call that from the Web Project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be generating scripts from migration to be executed in the production.
What works for me is to use
Update-Database -Script

That creates a script with a 'migration difference',
which you can manually apply as an SQL script on the target server database (and you should get the right migration table rows inserted etc.).

Personally, I don't trust automatic updates in 'live' scenarios, and I always prefer manual database administration (i.e. there is a problem with permissions needed to create or alter Db - not to mention shared hosting etc.) - but from what I've seen migrations are pretty solid when it comes to synchronizing (in fact, the only way to 'untie' them normally is to remove the Db and force full/fresh update).
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for immediate reply Arunkumar. I got the way from your points.